# Set FlowPanel Height to 100% when inside a ScrollPanel?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

I have the following GWT ui binder Panel structure:

```
<g:ScrollPanel ui:field="scrollPanel">
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="contentPanel">
        </g:FlowPanel>
</g:ScrollPanel>
```

The scrollPanel has height 100% which I can prove when is set a background color for this panel. The problem is that I cannot set the FlowPanel to height 100%.

**How do I set the FlowPanel which is inside the ScrollPanel to height 100%?**

Comment: It's a very unusual requirement to set height of a FlowPanel. Typically, you simply add content to the FlowPanel, and it expands vertically as necessary. Then, when it reaches the height of your ScrollPanel, a scroll-bar will appear. Why do you need to set the height of both panels to 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how `scrollpanel` took `100%`? AFAIK `100%` height does not work, you have to either specify `inner element` height or parent element height.

If you specify parent element height like `scroll panel` than flow panel set `100%` relative to it.Either specify scrollpanel height or flow panel height.

I don't know your requirement, but I would suggest better to specify scrollpanel height. so it will provide you scroll while increasing inside elements height.

Comment: ScrollPanel can take 100% height, because it takes height from its parent.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin ok. thanks. That I don't know. But op want to set height. is it possible to define `100%` without fixing parent elemenet height?

Comment: Typically you use ScrollPanel inside a LayoutPanel, or other widget that provides size to its children. This is how ScrollPanel "knows" when to show a scroll-bar.